# Accessing List from outside, missing generic type

Tags: java, generics

*EDIT: It's an Eclipse Problem(?). Eclipse shows an error but compiles it, seems to have something to do with Java 8 and Type Casting.*

I've a class that has a `List<E>` field. If I access it inside of the class I get `List<E>`.
But if I access the List from outside, I only get `List` without generic types. And if I access it's elements I only get an `Object`, instead of an `E` 
But in my Code I need explicit the `E`, so how can I change/fix that, so that the List is returned without removing the generics and without explicit casting?

Class with List:

```
public class ListClass {

    private List<String> list;

    public ListClass(){

        list = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public List<String> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Containg class:

```
public class ContainingClass {

    private ListClass lc;

    public ContainingClass(){

        lc = new ListClass();
    }

    public ListClass getListClass(){
        return lc;
    }

}
```

Now the problem:

```
    ContainingClass cc = new ContainingClass();

    String str = cc.getListClass().getList().get(0);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 Error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String"
```

But why?

Comment: Sounds like the getter for your field is using a raw type.

Comment: @Keppil See my `#getHashMap()` in Question, is it using a raw type?

Comment: No, that should work. Can you also share your calling code?

Comment: That shows up as `Set<K>` in my IDE. Your `Main` class doesn't compile though, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: The real class compiles without any errors

Comment: Your actual code must be different. It would be helpful to have a code example that reproduces the anomaly you are seeing in your actual code. It sounds like your `X` class actually has type parameters and you are using a raw `X`.

Comment: Will post real full code soon

Comment: First, don't post links, put the code directly in the question. Second, don't post the entire code. Trim it down to a minimal program that still displays the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer refers to [Revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26266386/3)

I think the problem is that the class should have the template parameter, and not the method.

```
public class X<K, V> {
    private HashMap<K, V> hashMap;

    public X(){
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<K,V> getHashMap(){
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem as Muli Yulzary's answer, `K` and `V` where fixed types, forgot to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's causing the problem:

```
public class X {
    private HashMap<K, V> hashMap;

    public X(){
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<K,V> getHashMap(){
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

When you instantiate X you leave no parameters, therefore it is a raw-type.

Your fix is to tell X which types of Keys and Values to use upon instantiation:

```
public class X<K, V> {
  private HashMap<K, V> hashMap;
  public X(){
    hashMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public HashMap<K,V> getHashMap(){
    return hashMap;
  }
```

Comment: In my case, `K` and `V` where fixed types, no variable types. Forgot to write it down.

Comment: Just cast the contents to your desired class.

Comment: Okay, thats what I'm doing now, but I thought about if it is possible without explicit casting.